# How do cost functions get decided in Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

I am new to ML, and I just learned linear regression and logistic regression.
I was wondering how do these cost functions get decided, and how are these derived? How do we know these cost functions are appropriate for particular problems?

In other words, I am not sure how these cost functions are proved to be accurate and appropriate for particular problems. Do we sometimes get to come up with our own cost function anytime in ML ?

Answer (score 3):

In a **proper** approach to ML you start with the problem you want to solve. Once you have a problem, you should ask yourself "what do I really care about?", "What is **really** my task here?" and the answer to that will provide a "perfect" loss function. The problem is, usually this "perfect" function cannot be really learned directly. Lets take classification for example, you want to have a model that distinguishes cats from dogs. One possible formalisation of the "perfect" loss would be "minimal number of incorrect answers". The problem is, function like this is not differentiable wrt. to model's parameters (or it is differentiable but provides 0 gradient). Consequently one often looks for **surrogates** which behave similarly, but are better suited for the learning methods we have. If instead of saying "minimal number of incorrect answers" you will say "minimum probabily of at least one incorrect answer" then the log-loss (the one used in logistic regression) is literally that.

So in short, typical path is:

1. Problem specification
2. Definition of perfect error measure
3. Selection of a surrogate loss according to the above and other constraints

For many problems there is no unique surrogate to pick, thus selection (or figuring out from scratch) of the optimal loss is the huge research area on its own.

Comment: Thank you. If you say we want to find a number of incorrect answers to have a model that distinguishes cats from dogs, does that mean we first have to guess from no where and make a training set, and then move on from that point? I still don't get the usage of perfect loss function here.

Comment: I meant that this is the task we are interested in. Then of course we will need data ,model, algorithms etc. Nevertheless the "perfect" error function is independent from data or model, it comes directly from what is the problem you are trying to solve, everything else is just a tool to achieve this goal.This "minimisation of incorrect classifications" is in particular - equivalent of accuracy in ML (which you cannot directly optimise), thus you choose (for example) log loss which is a decent surrogate.

Comment: Could you tell me the difference between cost function and the loss function that you are mentioning in your answer?

Comment: Loss function is what we use to model actual error, "cost" is usually slightly broader term which might also include some regularisation etc. So (but this is just linguistics) each loss is a cost function, but there are cost functions which are not "just" losses, but involve some additional terms. For the sake of this problem though they are pretty much the same objects.